# Data binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I am new to AngularJS and have a pretty basic problem I guess.

I have a drop-down list and based on the selection I want a table underneath to update with the belonging information.

```
<div ng-controller="RightCtrl as right">
  <select ng-model="right.selectedModule">
    <option ng-repeat="module in right.modules" value="{{module.id}}">{{module.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <th>Right name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="module in right.modules | filter: right.isCurrent">
  <tr ng-repeat="selRight in module.rights">
    <td right-id="{{selRight.id}}">{{selRight.name}}</td>
    <td>
      {{selRight.description}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/EN3S9/) and appreciate every help. Probably I am not completely understanding the concept yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to filter based on the selected object like:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="module in right.modules | filter:right.selectedModule">
```

Here is the full demo:

[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mzC8/)

Comment: Great! Thanks! I guess I haven't understood exactly how the filter work. How does the filter know on what parameter to filter on?